# T distribution for other functions than the mean

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, inference, t-distribution

If there are $X_1,\cdots,X_n \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ independent random variables, then their mean $n \cdot \overline X = X_1 + \cdots + X_n $ has the property that it is independent of $(n-1)S = \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})$. Therefore
$$
T(U) = \frac{U}{S/n^{1/2}}
$$
has the t-distribution in the case $U = \overline{X} - \mu$. For any $i,j \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, I imagine the statistics $T(X_i - \mu)$ and $T(X_i - X_j)$ appear quite frequently in applications. I want to know whether the t-distribution or the normal distribution is the better approximation in these cases.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about which property you want to generalize?

Comment: I am not making a case for anything. This version is not and the first two versions were not in a form suitable for this site: please see our help at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask, which begins "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Presently the question is too vague about "applications" and is impossible, therefore, to answer definitively.

Comment: Why is this version not suitable? Of course I don’t want the answer to this version, but I should know which rule the current version is violating.

Comment: @whuber which rule is it?